# GParted PXE Boot Fails at Root FS mount - Kernel Panic

Tags: gparted

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dmFa.jpg[image: Can't mount Root FS]
I have GParted setup almost identically to as described in the website help:

https://gparted.org/livepxe.php

The only difference between that the root directory is not / rather /GParted

The vmlinuz and initrd seem to boot ok.
The filesystem.squashfs is loaded via http and I can successfully wget it.

However, when it try to mount of the filesystem.squashfs, I have a problem as shown in the red box.

Mounting root file system ... /init: .: line 225: can't open '/scripts/GParted/live'

I'm not sure where /scripts/GParted/live is.  I'm also not sure how it would get a directory in front of my root /GParted  However, the system manages to find /scripts/init-premount

My PXE default here:

```
LABEL GParted Live
MENU LABEL GParted Live
kernel GParted/live/vmlinuz
APPEND initrd=GParted/live/initrd.img boot=GParted/live config components union=overlay username=user noswap noeject ip= vga=788 fetch=http://10.1.200.1/GParted/live/filesystem.squashfs
ENDTEXT
```

Where have I gone astray?

Answer (score 1):

The `/scripts/init-premount` lives inside the GParted `initrd.img` file.

The error message suggests the system is running into trouble on line 225 of script `/init` within the initrd image.

The line 225 of that script is:

```
. /scripts/${BOOT}
```

And the `${BOOT}` variable gets its value from the `boot=` boot parameter earlier.

So, the mistake is in assuming that if you put the `filesystem.squashfs` file into a sub-directory on the web server, you need to adjust the value of the `boot=` option to match. That is incorrect.

The `boot=` option specifies the *boot mode*: `local`, `nfs`, or `live`. This causes the script system (= `initramfs-tools` from Debian) to run the corresponding script in the `/scripts/` directory. `/scripts/live` exists in the initrd.img file, but `/scripts/GParted/live` doesn't.

So, change the APPEND line of your PXE bootloader configuration to:

```
APPEND initrd=GParted/live/initrd.img boot=live config components union=overlay username=user noswap noeject ip= vga=788 fetch=http://10.1.200.1/GParted/live/filesystem.squashfs
```

...and then it should work.